# Replacing command line arguments while preserving spaces

Tags: shell, options, whitespace

I would like to selectively replace a command-line argument that is being passed to automatically format it for the downstream command being executed.  The argument will have spaces and that is the point of contention.

I'm presently doing this:

```
set -- $(echo $* | sed -e "s/$_ARG/--description=\"$_ID - $_SUMMARY\"/")
```

The new argument, `--description="$_ID - $_SUMMARY"` gets split.

I run a downstream command:

```
<cmd> "$@"
```

I may have any number of arguments, but a sample use case is:

FROM

```
activity --description='handle null'
```

TO:

```
activity --description='$SOME_VARIABLE - handle null'
```

Ultimately, when I run the downstream command even with "$@" it is already split there, so it doesn't work as I intend.  It ends up like

```
activity --description=value - handle null
```

`--description=value`, `-`, `handle`, and `null` then are considered separate arguments.

Comment: I believe you want `$@` instead of `$*` but didn't look too deeply at your example - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898681/836748

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco In this case, the main issue is that the command substitution results in a single , unquoted, string, which is being split (and globbed) by the shell. It is unclear from the question what the arguments are that are being passed to the script, if all of them should be modified, and how the modification should happen (we don't know what's in `$_ARG`).

Comment: Is the `--description` option that you want to change always directly followed by `=` and some string, or may there be a space between the long option and its option-argument?

Comment: @Kusalananda - Yes, the --description option will always be directly followed by a = and some value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code.  One of them is using `$*` unquoted, which will cause the shell to split the original arguments into words on whatever characters are in `$IFS` (space, tab, newline, by default) and apply filename globbing on the generated words.  Quoting `$*` as `"$*"` is also not quite what you want if you ever want to support multiple arguments containing spaces, tabs or newlines as this would be a single string.  Switching to using `"$@"` would not help as `echo` would just produce a each argument with spaces in-between for `sed` to read.

`echo` may do special processing of any string containing backslash sequences like `\n` and `\t`, depending on the shell and its current settings. In some shells, `echo -n` may not output `-n` (there may be other problematic strings too, like `-e`).

Using `sed` to modify the arguments would possibly work on a single argument if you're happy treating it as text (arguments could potentially be multi-line strings), but in this case you are applying some editing script on all arguments at once, which may misfire.

What splits the resulting string though, is the non-quoting of the command substitution used with `set`.  This re-splits the result from `sed` and applies filename globbing on the result again.

You will need to parse the command line options that you intend to modify.
In short, loop over the arguments, and modify the ones you want to modify.

The following `sh` script adds the string `hello -`  at the start of the option-argument of each instance of the `--description` long option.  If the long option is immediately followed by a space, as in `--description "my thing"`, then this is rewritten with a `=`, as if the script had been called with `--description="my thing"`, before this is modified into the final `--description="hello - my thing"`.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

SOME_VARIABLE=hello

skip=false

for arg do
    if "$skip"; then
        skip=false
        continue
    fi

    # Re-write separate option-argument with "=".
    # This consumes an extra argument, so need to skip
    # next iteration of the loop.
    case $arg in
        --description)
            arg=--description=$2
            shift
            skip=true
    esac

    # Add the value "$SOME_VARIABLE - " to the start of the
    # option-argument of the --description long option.
    case $arg in
        --description=*)
            arg=--description="$SOME_VARIABLE - ${arg#--description=}"
    esac

    # Put the (possibly modified) argument back at the end
    # of the list of arguments and shift off the first item.
    set -- "$@" "$arg"
    shift
done

# Print out the list of arguments as strings within "<...>":
printf '<%s>\n' "$@"
```

`${arg#--description=}` removes the prefix string `--description=` from the value of `$arg`, leaving the original option-argument string.

Example run:

```bash
$ sh ./script -a -b --description="my thing" -c -d --description "your thing" -e
<-a>
<-b>
<--description=hello - my thing>
<-c>
<-d>
<--description=hello - your thing>
<-e>
```

The code may be simplified significantly if you always will be expecting to have the long option and its option-argument delimited by a `=` character:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

SOME_VARIABLE=hello

for arg do
    # Add the value "$SOME_VARIABLE - " to the start of the
    # option-argument of the --description long option.
    case $arg in
        --description=*)
            arg=--description="$SOME_VARIABLE - ${arg#--description=}"
    esac

    # Put the (possibly modified) argument back at the end
    # of the list of arguments and shift off the first item.
    set -- "$@" "$arg"
    shift
done

printf '<%s>\n' "$@"
```

Test run using same arguments as above (the second instance of `--description` will not be modified as it does not match the pattern `--description=*`):

```bash
$ sh ./script -a -b --description="my thing" -c -d --description "your thing" -e
<-a>
<-b>
<--description=hello - my thing>
<-c>
<-d>
<--description>
<your thing>
<-e>
```

---

A `bash` variant of the shorter second script from above, using shell pattern matching with `[[ ... ]]` in place of `case ... esac`, and using an array to hold the possibly modified arguments during the course of the loop:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

SOME_VARIABLE=hello

args=()
for arg do
    if [[ $arg == --description=* ]]; then
        arg=--description="$SOME_VARIABLE - ${arg#--description=}"
    fi

    args+=( "$arg" )
done

set -- "${args[@]}"

printf '<%s>\n' "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I removed sed altogether and now it works.

Answer (score 9):

In ksh93, zsh or bash, you can do:

```
set -- "${@/#--description=*/--description=$NEW_DESCRIPTION}"
```

To substitute positional parameters starting (`#` anchors the pattern at the start) with `--description=` with `--description=<contents-of-NEW_DESCRIPTION-variable`.

With `ksh93`, that can be shortened to:

```
set -- "${@/#@(--description=)*/\1$NEW_DESCRIPTION}"
```

The equivalent with `zsh -o extendedglob`:

```
set -- "${@/#(#b)(--description=)*/$match[1]$NEW_DESCRIPTION}"
```

But maybe you can also just do:

```
set -- "$@" "--description=$NEW_DESCRIPTION"
```

Most utilities accept taking the same option several times, and it's the last occurrence that takes precedence¹. For example:

```
$ echo x | grep -H --label=foo --label=bar .
bar:x
```

In `zsh`, you can do:

```
argv[(i)--description=*]=--description=$NEW_DESCRIPTION
```

To replace the first argument starting with `--description=` with `--description=<contents-of-NEW_DESCRIPTION-variable`, or adding it as a new argument at the end if none is found.

Or:

```
argv[(I)--description=*]=--description=$NEW_DESCRIPTION
```

Same except it's the last occurrence that is replaced and it's inserted at the start if not found.

It's also possible to replace that one argument with more than one with:

```
argv[(i)--description=*]=(--description=$NEW_DESCRIPTION --other-args)
```

Or to replace a `--description` argument and its following one with `--description=$NEW_DESCRIPTION`:

```
argv[n=argv[(i)--description],n+1]=--description=$NEW_DESCRIPTION
```

(again, adding that at the end if `--description` is not found among the elements).

To remove *all* arguments starting with `--description=` and adding one at the end:

```
set -- "${@:#--description=*}" --description=$NEW_DESCRIPTION
```

In `bash` 4.4+, another option to do some transformation on arguments is to resort to `perl`, passing the positional parameters as arguments and reading them back as a NUL-delimited list (since `bash` variables can't contain NULs anyway):

```
readarray -td '' newargs < <(
  SEARCH="$_ARG" REPLACE='--description=something' perl -l0e '
    for (@ARGV) {
      s/\Q$ENV{SEARCH}\E/$ENV{REPLACE}/;
      print;
    }' -- "$@"
)
set -- "${newargs[@]}"
```

More appropriate than `sed` with which you'd have to do some escaping for both SEARCH and REPLACE.

---

<sup>¹ except for the cumulative ones like the `--quiet --quiet` that is more quiet than `--quiet` with some utilities, or the `-o pid -o ppid` of `ps` to specify several output fields. There are cases where the order matters. For instance, changing `--description=foo --no-description` to `--description=bar --no-description` may not do the same thing as changing it to `--description=foo --no-description --description=bar`.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The output from a command substitution is a stream of bytes, read to a single string in the shell. There's no information there which whitespace is supposed to be part of a single argument, and which whitespace is supposed to separate the arguments from each other.

But if you have the GNU toolset and Bash, and want to use sed to process the arguments, you could use the fact that the arguments (like any variables in Bash and most other shells) are C strings, and can't contain the NUL byte. GNU sed can use NUL as a line separator, and Bash can read a set of NUL-terminated strings to an array with `readarray`. (You can't use word splitting to split the output from the command substitution on NULs.)

So e.g. something like this:

```
# test arguments
set -- activity --description='handle null'
SOME_VARIABLE="foo bar"

# prints args NUL-terminated, run through sed, read them in to the array 'new_args'
new_args=()
readarray -t -d '' new_args < <(printf "%s\0" "$@" | sed -ze "s/^--description=/&$SOME_VARIABLE - /")
# move the values from the array to the positional parameters $1, $2 ...
set -- "${new_args[@]}"
```

`printf "%s\0" "$@"` prints the positional parameter with NULs at the end, `sed -z` tells sed to use NUL as the line separator, and the sed command adds the contents of `$SOME_VARIABLE` after the `=` in `--description=...`.

Note that `$SOME_VARIABLE` is embedded in the sed command, so the usual caveats apply, namely that anything special to sed (like `/&\` and newline) will break the command. Also, the `printf` will print at least one element even if there are no positional parameters, so if that's a concern, wrap the whole thing in `if [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; then ...`.